# How to run docker on self hosted Azure agent as non root ? (agent is locked by MS to run as root)

Tags: docker, azure-devops

As you can't install Agent as a root, and docker requires root to run a commands, how is it possible to use self-hosted Azure build agents ?

I have installed the agent as non-root as per Agent requirements and installed docker as root.

User that is used to run agent cannot access the docker ;/

Answer (score 1):

You can run the following commands in bash task.

```bash
sudo usermod -a -G docker $(whoami)
sudo chmod 0666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Answer (score -1):

Check the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops

You can set up an Azure Pipelines self-hosted agent to run inside a Windows Server Core (for Windows hosts), or Ubuntu container (for Linux hosts) with Docker. You'll pass a few [environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops#environment-variables) to `docker run` which configure the agent to connect to Azure Pipelines or Azure DevOps Server. For example:

```
docker run -e AZP_URL=<Azure DevOps instance> -e AZP_TOKEN=<PAT token> -e AZP_AGENT_NAME=mydockeragent dockeragent:latest
```

Comment: I do not wish to run docker based build agent due to certain limitations of certain build agents. I was asking if this is possible to run in this specific use case. I know that I can run docker build agent.

Comment: How about creating the docker group and adding your user as [this documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/) mentioned? - container: ubuntu
    image: ubuntu:16.04
    options: '--group-add docker' (https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/2056#issuecomment-454897571).